# Projective bundles over a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am wondering about something.. Say that I have a variety $X$ with a projective bundle $\pi:P \rightarrow X$ (for simplicity let's say that $X$ is complex projective, and this bundle is locally trivial in the analytic topology). 
The automorphisms of the fibers $\pi^{-1}(y)$ are $PGL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. So, I think that there should be an $O_{X}$-algebra structure on the sheaf of local sections, but I can't really imagine what it could be. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Elliot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra you can write down, but you don't get it by looking at local sections of this bundle (which don't even have a vector space structure). Rather, you have a $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$-torsor, and since this is the automorphism group of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, there is an associated bundle (an Azumaya algebra) of matrix algebras. It's the sheaf of sections of this bundle that you want.

Comment: You mean "of"? Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is actually exactly the context in which I am asking this question. I have found some amazing notes: http://stanford.edu/~jbooher/expos/brauer1.pdf and http://math.uga.edu/~pete/trivial2003.pdf relating the brauer group to projective bundles. I guess I am not understanding this: $H^{1}(PGL)$ corresponds to transition maps for projective bundles, how do I see "why" I need to define (azumaya) algebras to describe these bundles?

Comment: I understand that there is a set-theoretic bijection between $H^{1}(PGL)$ and azumaya algebras.. but can I see how these algebras correspond to the projective bundles geometrically?

Comment: @Elliot: are you familiar with the associated bundle construction in, say topology? Given a principal $G$-bundle on a space $X$ and any space $F$ on which $G$ acts, you get an associated bundle with fibers $F$. This is a special case of that construction, adapted to algebraic geometry.

Comment: Oh right.. I think I see! (I am familiar with this notion as far as the chapter from Serre's "galois cohomology book). So the situation is that we have two possible fiber bundles with $PGL$ acting on the fibers. So both a projective bundle, and the bundle of matrix algebras are associated to each other by "twisting" with a $PGL_{n}$-torsor. Is this the idea? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can even functorially construct the projective bundle from the matrix algebra bundle by doing something like fiberwise taking rank $1$ projections.

Comment: Hmm interesting.. So is it true that the use of azumaya algebras to study projective bundles is not necessarily "intrinsic", but natural to consider given the bijection between these algebras and $H^{1}(PGL)$? (fiber bundles that are twisted of a torsor are not canonically isomorphic)

Comment: Dunno. I mean, I personally care about Azumaya algebras not up to isomorphism but up to Morita equivalence (this is what is relevant to the Brauer group), and on the other hand I don't particularly care about projective bundles.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I really understand it now. What's really interesting to me is that we can relate any kind of fiber bundle to each other with specified automorphisms of the fibers, just via the torsor. So really the $G$-torsor is the object that is the "most interesting" here to study (in some sense, a more universal(?) object?)